# How to optimize each line of code using backbone.js and underscore.js templates

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have one dropdown list which listed years. Now i want to select value (based on model value) using single line not checking for all line.

*This code is working*

```
<select class="input-small" id="year" name="year">
    <option <%= year == 2013 ? 'selected' : '' %>>2013</option>
    <option <%= year == 2012 ? 'selected' : '' %>>2012</option>
    <option <%= year == 2011 ? 'selected' : '' %>>2011</option>
    <option <%= year == 2010 ? 'selected' : '' %>>2010</option>
    <option <%= year == 2009 ? 'selected' : '' %>>2009</option>
    <option <%= year == 2008 ? 'selected' : '' %>>2008</option>
    <option <%= year == 2007 ? 'selected' : '' %>>2007</option>
    <option <%= year == 2006 ? 'selected' : '' %>>2006</option>
</select>
```

but i wanted to optimize every line of code to single line.
for example:

```
<select class="input-small" id="year" name="year">
    <option>2013</option>
    <option>2012</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2008</option>
    <option>2007</option>
    <option>2006</option>
</select>
<% ('#year').val(year) %> //This is not set my value as per mode
```

Comment: You can select option with jQuery using `$("#year option:contains('+year+')")` selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// pass array of years to your template
var years = [2006, 2007, 2008];
// in your template
<select class="input-small" id="year" name="year">
  <% _.each(years, function (val) { %>
  <option <% year === val && print('selected') %>><%= val %></option>
  <% }) %>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick solution. my vote +1. i have modified line as `<option <%= (year == val) ? 'selected' : '' %>><%= val %></option>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery:

```
$("#year option:contains('"+year+"')").attr("selected", "selected");
```